# metasploit python http.client error missing

Tags: python, http, debian, metasploit

I am newbie with Metasploit-framework
Just installed it on a Debian 9.7 and running it from a python program got the following error:

```
in <module> from metasploit.msfrpc import MsfRpcClient File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/metasploit/msfrpc.py", line 2, in <module> from http.client import HTTPConnection, HTTPSConnection ImportError: No module named http.client
```

If needed, I'll provide more info. 
I'm sorry in advance if the question is pretty lame but i havn't had find any solution so far.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: First try using python3 instead of python 2 which doesn't have any `http.client`. Secondly, which python package did you install?